# How to query a STUN server with JavaScript to get public IP and Port?

Tags: javascript, html, nat, stun

I am trying to find some code example to query a STUN server to get my public IP and Port, using JavaScript. Perhaps using the server at

http://www.stunserver.org

While the STUN specification is explained here http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3489.txt ( this is a long document, obviously I don't expect you to read it), I have been unable to find any code example at all, which would make my life easier. Something like

```
function getMyIPAndPort() {
//query stun server for it
}
```

Thank you

Comment: 12 views and no answers..... Chuck Norris please help!!! :(

Comment: Are you talking about server-side nodejs application or javascript running in a web browser?

Comment: Oh come on. There should be an Answer.

Answer (score 3):

you can get both local and external IP

```
 function  determineIPs() {
    const pc = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [ {urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'} ] });
    pc.createDataChannel('');
    pc.createOffer().then(offer => pc.setLocalDescription(offer))
    pc.onicecandidate = (ice) => {
        if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate) {
          console.log("all done.");
          pc.close();   
          return;
        }
        let split = ice.candidate.candidate.split(" ");
        if (split[7] === "host") {
          console.log(`Local IP : ${split[4]}`);
        } else {
          console.log(`External IP : ${split[4]}`);
         }
    };
  }
determineIPs();
```

e.g. https://jsbin.com/zosayiyidu/1/edit?js,console

the STUN server is for external IP.
make sure you are not behind any proxy that prevents access to  stun:stun.l.google.com:19302  or use a different STUN server

Answer (score 2):

Very late answer. Have a look at this mini project: https://diafygi.github.io/webrtc-ips/

It does give you the IP, but doesn't seem to give the port. However, if you look at these lines: `//match just the IP address
var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3})/
var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(candidate)[1];`

It seems that they remove the port. I am not sure, but you can play with it to find out.

Answer (score 1):

I've also check the project (https://diafygi.github.io/webrtc-ips), even when it's a fantastic script I did not like too much. I mean, the reason is that it assumes whichs IPs are public and private. If the IP is not 10/8, 172.16/12 or 192.168/16 it's a public IPv4. This is not always true. You can (unfortunately) have an IPv4 address of other range in your LAN and NAT it. 
  This ideas is to obtain the IP address return by the STUN Server, not assume it.

Regards,